# What is a painless and free way to test Internet Explorer 10 on a Mac?

Tags: macos, windows, virtualbox, internet-explorer

I’m a graphics (minimal tech) guy struggling to find an easy way of testing Internet Explorer on my Mac. I don’t have access to a Windows PC, and I don’t want to spend any money to test IE.

Obviously Chrome, Firefox, Opera (and Sarari) are interchangeable between the Mac and Windows OS. I can’t seem to find a clear method to test Internet explorer on a Mac. I wouldn’t use IE for any other reason and really don’t want to fork over any money to Microsoft if I don’t have to.

I found [this tutorial](https://centroy.com/blog/testing-internet-explorer-mac-its-actually-quite-easy) which seems nicely written and detailed about how to do this. In a nutshell it  explains all I need is a copy of VirtualBox (free virtualization SW), and a developer copy of Windows 8 (free? really?) and I can test IE10 no problem. Anyone else tried this approach? Does Microsoft dumb down IE in the developer copy? Is there a better/easier way before starting down this path? Here's the tutorial I was talking about: 
https://centroy.com/blog/testing-internet-explorer-mac-its-actually-quite-easy

Comment: With the answer already in the question it's a bit difficult to understand what you are actually looking for.

Comment: Yep, you can download Windows and run it with Virtualbox all for free to test IE and it works great. The only limitation is that it will eventually expire after a few months. Its essentially a fully functioning copy of Windows XP, 7 or 8 (your pick) and choice of IE to test with.

Answer (score 2):

It’s the same end result as the tutorial above, but [ievms](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms) is way easier—all the steps are automated. Just run:

`curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | env IEVMS_VERSIONS="10" bash`

and you’ll have a fully functional VM with IE10.